# How to apply language translation on requires field when showing other table field values

Tags: web2py

In my application I have to specify a title field as below

```
Field('title', type='string',label=T('Title'),requires=IS_IN_DB(db,db.t_title.id, '%(name)s',orderby=db.t_title.id))
```

all the title options are mentioned in the t_title table.
For example in t_title table I have values Mr. and Mrs. For english language this is fine.
But for german language I have to display Herr and Frau.

How can I set language translation 'T()' to title values. So I can add the corresponding title names in other language files.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
IS_IN_DB(db, db.t_title.id, lambda r: T(r.name), orderby=db.t_title.id)
```

The label argument to IS_IN_DB can be a function that takes a Row object and returns a label for that row.